# Aligning link_to button with input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, alignment, row, link-to

So i have this link_to button and an input field. I just want them to be aligned, but the button is being placed at the same height that the label, not the input, so this is the result:

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="column-selection row">
    <div class="select-to-be-cloned">
      <div class="col-md-2 traffic-columns">
        <%= f.input :select1, collection: @traffic_vault.sort + [["------ Aggregations ------ ", ""]] + @traffic_vault_aggregations.sort, include_blank: false, label: "Select Dimensions (*)", input_html: {class: "remember_timestamp", type: "text" } %>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row col-md-4">
        <%= link_to "Apply function.", "#", :class => "btn btn-success", :style =>"width:auto !important;", :onclick => "apply_function(0)" %>
        <%= link_to "Rename It", "#", :class => "btn btn-success",:style =>"width:auto !important;",  :onclick => "rename(0)" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Im pretty sure that this can be solved placing an special class but i dont know what class. I tried with align-self-end because i saw it in some other post but nothing, still same problem. I've also been trying with the form-group, form-inline and form-control but without success.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply css like this will pull buttons down

margin-top: 10px;

Comment: Although this works, i'd like to know how to make this without hard-coding anything about margins and so. Anyway, thanks!